# Random bytes get displayed when parsing the string and storing it back as char array

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to parse a string like `HTTP POST /abc/def/ghi/klm/mno`, where I want to separate the different components namely the protocol, the HTTP verb, and the path.

I am using `strtok` function and then copying the string using `strlen` function. But when I try to print the string, it gives some random bytes as shown below.

[image]

I cannot understand the reason for this. Here is what I am doing.

```
struct my_con {
    char protocol[100];
    char method[100];
    char uri[100];
};

char* header = "HTTP POST /abc/def/ghi/klm/mno";

void my_func(my_con **mc) {
   char* p = strtok(header," ");
   int c = 0;
   while(p != NULL) {

       if(count == 0) strncpy((**mc).protocol, p, strlen(p));
       elseif(count == 1) strncpy((**mc).method, p, strlen(p));
       elseif(count == 2) strncpy((**mc).uri, p, strlen(p));
       count++;
       p = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you pass `strlen(p)` to `strncpy`? Use `100`.

Comment: Regarding the length issue, better yet use `sizeof (*mc)->protocol - 1`. The `-1` is so you can add a terminator to the string, as there's a case when [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) doesn't add the terminator.

Comment: @user3121023 Could you please give an example?

Comment: The `while` loop looks like an infinite loop , `p` is never modified inside the loop. Neither is `count`.

Comment: @JoëlHecht Edited (was a mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strspn` and `strcspn` can be used to iterate through a literal string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char* header = "HTTP POST /abc/def/ghi/klm/mno";
    char temp[100];
    int offset = 0;
    int span = 0;

    while ( header[offset]) {
        span = strspn ( header + offset, " ");//count spaces
        offset += span;//advance offset past spaces
        span = strcspn ( header + offset, " ");//count non-space
        if (span && span < 99) {
            strncpy ( temp, header + offset, span);
            temp[span] = 0;//terminate
            printf ( "%s\n", temp);
        }
        offset += span;//advance offset past non-space
    }

    return 0;
}
```